# JWT Token - Audience, Issuer and subdomains

Tags: azure, authentication, token, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile App with custom authentication. JWT Tokens are created using Audience, Issuer and SigningKey.
The thing is I deployed the app in multiple regions each with its url which is a subdomain of mydomainname.com.
Can I use a wildcard url like *.mydomainname.com for Audience and Issuer?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using region affinity, so a user that is going to, say, US-West, goes to US-West for their entire session.  In this case, the regional JWT will remain in region and you won't have to deal with this.

If you do need to deal with this, then you will have to go even more custom, verifying and validating the token yourself.  In this case, you can turn off App Service Authentication and just validate the token with a custom audience/issuer.

Comment: I use traffic manager whose url is the audience and issuer and it works fine. But when I want to test the web api for a given region I can't as the token is only valid when I call the traffic manager endpoint.

Comment: For testing, construct a JWT with the appropriate audience/issuer separately, then use that.

Comment: Good idea! Any JWT token website you know about? Don't I need my signing key? As posted on github I have no idea where it as I,ve never set it up and I can't see it defined when using Kudu.

Comment: I'm not sure whether jwt.io would work - it validates no problem.  I used the node SDK to quickly generate one.  In Kudu, the signing key is called WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY and is created when you turn on App Service Authentication / Authorization.

Comment: I don't have WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY nowhere (see my post on azure mobile app github). But I debugged on server to get it. I tried jwt.io. I don't manage to get it working yet. I'll update the question with info.